# Angular2 - Using POST with angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, post, get

I am playing around with angular-in-memory-web-api for Angular 2. So far I have only been using GET calls and it's working well.

The API I'm going to call is only using POST calls so I began rewriting my GET calls to POST calls, but then they stopped returning the mock data. In my test function bellow, I want to get the data as a TestResponse object by an id:

```
postTest(id: string): Promise<TestResponse> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.testUrl, JSON.stringify({ testId: id }), { headers: this.headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as TestResponse)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And the mock data:

```
    let test = [
        { testId: 'e0d05d2b-3ec3-42ae-93bc-9937a665c4d6', missingData: 'qwerty', moreMissingData: 'asdfgh' },
        { testId: 'dccef969-b9cf-410a-9973-77549ec47777', missingData: 'qwerty', moreMissingData: 'asdfgh' },
        { testId: '20716fd7-1f50-4a12-af16-52c009bc42ab', missingData: 'qwerty', moreMissingData: 'asdfgh' }
    ];
```

If I understand this right, this code will assume that I want to create something and is therefor bouncing my testId back together with id: 1 (which doesn't even follow my data structure).

So, my question is, how can I get my mock data with POST calls?

Comment: in-memory-web-api is just for play a little and familiarize with the framework. If you want to go deep in your learning, you should implement a "real" fake backend. check out this example : https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular2-registration-login-example/blob/master/app/_helpers/fake-backend.ts

Comment: Thanks, the example works very well.

Comment: Looks like a good example. Is there a similar example for latest versions of Angular and RxJS

Comment: Does it mean that we can not fake the addition of a new data in memory, and then return the new data set from in memory module ?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to override HTTP methods in your in memory data service implementation.

In the overridden method (e.g POST), it is possible to react to the collection name (via the `RequestInfo` parameter) to provide specific functionality on a per-endpoint/collection basis.

A provided example deals with GET calls only: https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/app/hero-in-mem-data-override.service.ts

From that, overriding the POST functionality could look like this:

```
import { InMemoryDbService, RequestInfo, STATUS, ResponseOptions } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class Your InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {

  // ...

  post(requestInfo: RequestInfo) {
    const collectionName = requestInfo.collectionName;
    if (collectionName === 'somedatatype') {
      // Intercept POST calls to the 'somedatatype' collection:
      // E.g. add some fields to our entity that would be set in the backend,
      const data = requestInfo.utils.getJsonBody(requestInfo.req);
      const collection = requestInfo.collection;
      data.extraField = 'hello';

      // set id to next highest number 
      data.id = collection.map(item => item.id).reduce((cur, next) => cur > next ? cur : next) + 1;

      // ... add the item to the collection
      collection.push(data);

      // forge the response
      const options: ResponseOptions = {
        body: { data  },
        status: STATUS.OK,
        headers: requestInfo.headers,
        url: requestInfo.url
      };

      // use createResponse$ to return proper response
      return requestInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => options);
    }

    // let the default POST handle all other collections by returning undefined
    return undefined; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was great. Life saver.