# Correct way to do a PUT or POST in angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular

Have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630421/angular2-using-post-with-angular-in-memory-web-api) but the question was unanswered. So asking this question again.

I was trying to implement a PUT. Which didn't work, I checked the `requestInformation`and `response` in `responseInterceptor`. It turns out that the control never reaches my `responseInterceptor`.

This is the http code:

```
put(url: string, body, options?:RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<StandardModelResponse>{
    console.log("inside put, url = ", url, " body = ", body);
    return this._http.put(url,body,this._updateRequestHeader(options)); 
}
```

The received log is:

[image]

My `InMemoryDbService` has a collection:

```
let sessionData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    loginActive: 0
  }
];
```

and it returns the collection like this:

```
return {sessionData}
```

I looked through the [source](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts), and yes indeed there is an implementation of post and put, but I could not find the `in-memory-backend.service.ts` file in my `node-modules` for debugging, instead a `in-memory-backend.service.js` is there. What is the right way to do this `POST` call, what am I missing here?

Comment: It should work. You have an example that _doesn't_? And what's not working about it (meaning what's the result)?

Comment: Check out [the source](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts). Towards the bottom, you'll see the post and put methods implemented

Comment: Thanks, checking out. Will let you know the status.

Comment: @peeskillet: Hi, I have updated my question, can you please have a look into it?

Comment: _"And what's not working about it (meaning what's the result)?"_

Comment: I have explained that. I don't get anything in my `responseInterceptor`. The collection, `sessionData` remains the same, although as shown in the log, I am sending `loginActive` as `1`. This is all, no errors come in the console.

Comment: Not sure the purpose of your interceptors. Take it out and what's the result? Maybe it is the problem

Comment: Did that, no result as such! Didn't get any response. Just clarifying, the collection on which I am doing a put will actually be updated in the file (class extending InMemoryDb)? I don't see that in the code, all I see is a `new ResponseOptions()` with the updated array.

Comment: _"Did that, no result as such! Didn't get any response"_ You realize that the default for POST and PUT is to not return any response. This is based on common practices with REST: POST should just set Location header with created URI with 201 status; PUT should just return 204 status. Both with no body. You can configure the service to send back the body if you want. When you configure the module in your app, pass as a second argument `forRoot(Service, {post204: false, put204: false})`

Comment: You can see all the possible configurtions [here in the source](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts#L94)

Comment: Many thanks, It took me so long to find that I was missing the `subscribe()` in my `save()`. Your comments were very helpful though. And its amazing how angular keeps the updated data in memory but doesn't write it to the file.

Comment: Damn... all of the GitHub links, in the question, and in these comments, take me to a Page Not Found screen.

Comment: @MikeGledhill Try https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/11.1.x/packages/misc/angular-in-memory-web-api and specifically https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.1.x/packages/misc/angular-in-memory-web-api/src/interfaces.ts as the angular-in-memory-web-api has been rolled into angular

Answer (score 0):

You can "override" (I am not sure if that is what is happening)  the post method by adding it in your implementation of InMemoryDbService

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { getStatusText, STATUS } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/http-status-codes';
import { ParsedRequestUrl, RequestInfo, RequestInfoUtilities, ResponseOptions } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/interfaces';
.....

  post(reqInfo: RequestInfo) {

  }
...
```

You can implement it to do something like the implementation of the get method like it is done here:
[source](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/app/hero-in-mem-data-override.service.ts)

I hope that helps. It seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty old question but I have not found any answer describing how to patch InMemoryDbService needing to customize or fix a handler of a PUT or POST operation. As I have recently faced a similar situation, I have decided to post my solution here so that somebody might find it useful.

As has already been mentioned above, *post* and *put* functions can be overridden. For instance, the code below inserts a new item in the *post* method and updates an existing item in the *put* method

```
export class InMemoryDatabase extends InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Superman'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Biowulf')
    ];
    return { heroes };
  }

  post(reqInfo: RequestInfo) {
    var collection = reqInfo.collection;
    // process only requests as /api/object/:id
    if (!collection)
      return reqInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => {
        const options: ResponseOptions = { status: STATUS.NOT_FOUND };
        return this.finishOptions(options, reqInfo);
      });

    // insert an object to the collection
    let item = reqInfo.utils.getJsonBody(reqInfo.req)
    item["id"] = this.genId(collection);
    collection.push(item);

    // respond
    return reqInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => {
      const options: ResponseOptions =
      {
        body: item,
        status: STATUS.OK
      }
      return this.finishOptions(options, reqInfo);
    });
  }

  genId(collection: any): number {
    return collection.length > 0 ? Math.max(...collection.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }

  put(reqInfo: RequestInfo) {
    var collection = reqInfo.collection;

    // process only requests as /api/object/:id
    if (!collection || !reqInfo.id)
      return reqInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => {
        const options: ResponseOptions = { status: STATUS.NOT_FOUND };
        return this.finishOptions(options, reqInfo);
      });

    // update an object
    let item = reqInfo.utils.findById(collection, reqInfo.id);
    const body = reqInfo.utils.getJsonBody(reqInfo.req)
    Object.assign(item, body);

    // respond
    return reqInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => {
      const options: ResponseOptions =
      {
        body: item,
        status: STATUS.OK
      }
      return this.finishOptions(options, reqInfo);
    });
  }

  private finishOptions(options: ResponseOptions, { headers, url }: RequestInfo) {
    options.statusText = getStatusText(options.status);
    options.headers = headers;
    options.url = URL;
    return options;
  }
}
```