# Angular-in-memory-web-api PUT returns null

Tags: angular, rest, angular-in-memory-web-api

I created this basic data service for *todos*:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Todo } from './todos.service';

export class TodosData implements InMemoryDbService {

createDb() {
    const todos: Todo[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'TODO 1',
        }
    ];
    return { todos };
}
```

}

Here is how the service is consumed:

```
const apiUrl = 'api/todos/'

// CREATE
create(todo: Todo){return this.http.post<Todo>(apiUrl, {...todo, id: null})}

// UPDATE
update(todo: Todo){return this.http.put<Todo>(apiUrl + todo.id, todo)}
```

When subscribing on the `create` fn (POST), then the new Todo is returned.

But when subscribing on the `update` fn (PUT), then `null` is returned.

Is that a bug or a feature?

When refreshing the list (GET) then the updated Todo is there as expected.

Is there a way to let the PUT also return the updated TODO instead of `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution here:
[Correct way to do a PUT or POST in angular-in-memory-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347621/correct-way-to-do-a-put-or-post-in-angular-in-memory-web-api#comment73782901_43347621)

PUT does not return by default.

But it can be enabled:
`HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(TodosData, { put204: false }),`